# Hire PI Developer to develop an analyitcs box based on raspberry pi

Tags: hardware

I am working on this new project to monitor signals from an STB box. I need a PI box to interface with the STB and i am looking for a PI developer? How do I hire someone?

Comment: You post job adverts (that means posting in relevant places, not a technical Q&A site)... obviously, you interview people (that means asking questions)... Not sure I'd want to work for a boss who has to ask "how do I hire someone", frankly.

Comment: @dm76 Oh I don't know, it would make a change to work for someone who was aware of their own limitations, not many bosses like that!

Comment: Sounds more like a freelance or contract thing than a bone fide job.  There are various "freelance programming" sites around if you search for them; they help you get connected and hold your money in escrow.

Answer (score 1):

Start by identifying what skills are required.

If you are unsure what skills you need hire a project manager.

For instance do you need someone who has ever used a Raspberry Pi? The Pi is just a generic ARM based system that commonly runs a flavour a Linux. Do you need an electrical engineer or just a code monkey?

What are requirements of the project? speed/cost/reliability/maintenace

Is this a full time role or contract?

Employment agencies will be able to steer you to candidates that are already offering their skills in a specific field, STB, python etc.

and then there is always http://careers.stackoverflow.com/uk/jobs